# Replacing instances in every string of an array

Tags: python, string, replace

I have reached the limits of my primitive abilities and I cannot get to grips with what guidance or answers I have been able to find.

Basically, I am trying to replace one set of characters with another, but only on the first instance of each string in an array on excel.

It was also meant to work only if certain characters are not present. I'll demonstrate:

```
        ["crcs00","1dlmc56","t5adai4444c","cQdd27"] 
becomes ["Crcs00","1Dlmc56","t5Xdai4444c","cQdd27"]
```

So as you can see, only the first appearance of c, a or d change, and only if Q, U or Z are not present.

This is what I managed to cobble together from the knowledge I have gained this last month:

```
def pointreplace(i):
    a = ["a","b","c","d"]
    A = ["X","Y","C","D"]
    Z = ["U","L","Q"]
    
    entry = list(i)
    for entry in list:
        if (Z not in entry):
            str.replace(a,A,1)

df["codemark"] = df["codemark"].apply(lambda x: pointreplace(x))
```

What I was expecting was for the changes to the characters as demonstrated in the first code block.

`TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable` is the error I get. I assume means I cannot use a, A and Z in the way I have. What I am meant to do is beyond me.

Comment: what exactly is `df["codemark"]`?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] (*read the link*).  All this code gives is `name 'df' is not defined`.  There are numerous other errors, but that's the first one.  The error you claim is from `for entry in list:`.  `list` is a type and isn't iterable.

Answer (score 1):

"for entry in list:" is wrong.  `list` is a type, not a variable.  You shouldn't need to convert the incoming to a list, anyway.  You can't do a whole set of replacements in one shot -- you have to do them in a loop.

ASSUMING each cell of your dataframe contains a list of items, this is what you need:

```
old = ["a","b","c","d"]
new = ["X","Y","C","D"]
Z = ["U","L","Q"]

def pointreplace(incoming):        
    outgoing = []
    for entry in incoming:
        if any (z in entry for z in Z):
            for o,n in zip(old,new):
                entry = entry.replace(o,n,1)
    return outgoing

df["codemark"] = df["codemark"].apply(pointreplace)
```

If your column actually contains individual strings, then that changes things a little bit.

```
old = ["a","b","c","d"]
new = ["X","Y","C","D"]
Z = ["U","L","Q"]

def pointreplace(incoming):    
    if any(z in incoming for z in Z):
        for o,n in zip(old,new):
            incoming = incoming.replace(o,n,1)
    return incoming

df["codemark"] = df["codemark"].apply(pointreplace)
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. I was able to make use of this.

Answer (score 0):

How about a native VBA solution since you're using excel:

Code output:

```
[crcs00, 1dlmc56, t5adai4444c, cQdd27] -input
[Crcs00, 1Dlmc56, t5Xdai4444c, cQdd27] -result
[Crcs00, 1Dlmc56, t5Xdai4444c, cQdd27] -expected, result == expected?: True
```

Code:

```
    Sub test()
    
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Array("crcs00", "1dlmc56", "t5adai4444c", "cQdd27")
        Debug.Print "[" + Join(arr, ", ") + "] -input"
        
        Dim a1, a2, Z As Variant
        a1 = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
        a2 = Array("X", "Y", "C", "D")
        Z = Array("U", "L", "Q")
        
        Dim j, pos, temppos, jtemp As Integer, repl As Boolean
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            For Each iZ In Z
                If InStr(arr(i), iZ) > 0 Then GoTo nexti
            Next
            pos = 0: repl = False: temppos = UBound(arr) + 1: jtemp = 0
            For j = LBound(a1) To UBound(a1)
                pos = InStr(arr(i), a1(j))
                If pos > 0 Then repl = True: If pos < temppos Then temppos = pos: jtemp = j
            Next j
            If repl = True Then arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), a1(jtemp), a2(jtemp), , 1)
nexti:
        Next i
        Debug.Print "[" + Join(arr, ", ") + "] -result"
        Dim e As Variant
        e = Array("Crcs00", "1Dlmc56", "t5Xdai4444c", "cQdd27")
        Debug.Print "[" + Join(e, ", ") + "] -expected, result == expected?: " + IIf(Join(arr, Chr(0)) = Join(e, Chr(0)), "True", "Falese")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to build on Tim's solution.

Here's what I think you're trying to do:

```
['crcs00', '1dlmc56', 't5adai4444c', 'cQdd27'] -input
['Crcs00', '1Dlmc56', 't5Xdai4444c', 'cQdd27'] -result
['Crcs00', '1Dlmc56', 't5Xdai4444c', 'cQdd27'] -expected, result == expected?: True
```

Here's the code to get you there (assuming you're probably using pandas dataframe, let me know if you're using numpy):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["crcs00","1dlmc56","t5adai4444c","cQdd27"], columns=["codemark"])
print(f'{list(df["codemark"])} -input')
a = ["a","b","c","d"]
A = ["X","Y","C","D"]
Z = ["U","L","Q"]

def pointreplace(incoming):
    if not any(z in incoming for z in Z):
        min_index_list = [incoming.find(o) if incoming.find(o) > -1 else len(incoming)+1 for i,o,n in zip([*range(len(a))],a,A)]
        min_index = min(range(len(min_index_list)), key=min_index_list.__getitem__)
        if min_index < len(incoming): incoming = incoming.replace(a[min_index],A[min_index],1)
    return incoming

df["codemark"] = df["codemark"].apply(pointreplace)
print(f'{list(df["codemark"])} -result')
expected = ["Crcs00", "1Dlmc56", "t5Xdai4444c", "cQdd27"]
print(f'{expected} -expected, result == expected?: {list(df["codemark"]) == expected}')
```

Comment: Very many thanks. This got me through my problem.

Comment: Fantastic! It was a fun project.